# Angular - responsive html container using css

Tags: html, css, angular

> I'm trying to get a result similar to the picture. A container can
> have multiple elements starting on that container or no element at
> all. The elements always have the same height and the height of the
> containers depends on the number of elements, if none, the height is
> the min height, if more than one the height must be enough to cover
> that element (the height of each element is 40px) and half of the next
> element.
>
> In the picture:
>
> - Elements 1 and 2 start in container 1;
> - Elements 3 and 4 start in container 2;
> - Containers 3 and 4 do not have elements starting on that containers (they should have the min height).

---

```
<div class="all">
  <div class="conts" *ngFor="let cont of container;  let i = index">
    <div class="cont" [ngStyle]="{'height': cont.numberOfElements + 'px'}">
      C{{i}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="test">
  <div class="els" *ngFor="let elm of el;  let i = index">
    <div class="el">
       El{{i}}
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
    .all {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.test {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 40px;  
}

.els {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.el {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid blue;

}

.const {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cont {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: left;
  min-height: 40px;
  height: var(--height);
}

.conts:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: green;
}
.conts:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

---

```
  el = [
    {start: new Date('1/1/2020')}, 
    {start: new Date('1/1/2021')}, 
    {start: new Date('1/1/2022')}, 
    {start: new Date('1/1/2023')}
    ]
 
    container = [
    {start: new Date('1/1/2019'), end: new Date('1/5/2021'), numberOfElements: 40*1},
    {start: new Date('1/5/2021'), end: new Date('1/5/2023'), numberOfElements: 40*0},
    {start: new Date('1/5/2023'), end: new Date('1/6/2023'), numberOfElements: 40*2},
    {start: new Date('1/6/2023'), end: new Date('1/1/2024'), numberOfElements: 40*1}
    ]
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the position: absolute solved the issue.